# Change Time and Date with AlarmManager by accessing the Android kernel

Tags: android, kotlin, kernel

Considering that we have full access to the `Android kernel`, we use the following function to change the time and date

```
 private fun setTime(hourOfDay: Int, minute: Int) {
    val c = Calendar.getInstance()
    c[Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY] = hourOfDay
    c[Calendar.MINUTE] = minute
    c[Calendar.SECOND] = 0
    c[Calendar.MILLISECOND] = 0
    val date = c.timeInMillis.coerceAtLeast(1194220800000L)
    if (date / 1000 < Int.MAX_VALUE) {
        (requireContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager).setTime(date)
    }
    requireContext().sendBroadcast(Intent(Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED))
}
```

Now, when we use this code in the `fragment`, sometimes when this code is executed, the `fragment` or the active page is automatically closed and call `onDestroy()` is called, but the date changes.
Is there another way to change the clock and time with `full access to the Android kernel`?

Another point is that when the time and date change, I want it to be applied immediately

Answer (score 0):

Directly altering the system time in Android from within an app is not recommended due to security and stability concerns. Attempting to change the time via the kernel or AlarmManager could lead to unexpected behavior, crashes, or your app being terminated by the system.

Android doesn't allow apps to directly change the system time for security reasons. The **`AlarmManager#setTime()`** method is not intended for changing the device's time, and doing so might cause the behavior you're experiencing.

If you need to update the system time in your app, consider using the **`AlarmManager`** to schedule a one-time alarm that triggers your time update logic at the desired time. However, it's crucial to note that this won't immediately change the system time but can execute your code to perform certain tasks at a specific time.

Here's an example of scheduling an alarm using **`AlarmManager`**:

```
private fun scheduleTimeUpdate(hourOfDay: Int, minute: Int) {
    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance().apply {
        set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay)
        set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute)
        set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
        set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0)
    }

    val alarmManager = requireContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
    val intent = Intent(requireContext(), TimeUpdateReceiver::class.java)
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(requireContext(), 0, intent, 0)

    alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.timeInMillis, pendingIntent)
}
```

Create a BroadcastReceiver to handle the scheduled alarm:

```
class TimeUpdateReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        // Perform your time update logic here
        // This logic will be executed when the alarm triggers
    }
}
```

Remember, this approach won't immediately change the system time but will execute your defined logic at the specified time.

If you require immediate system time changes, consider other options available through root access and system-level privileges, although these methods are not recommended due to potential system instability and security risks.